# Magento2 : How to database schema upgrade

Tags: magento2, database, setup-script, upgrade-script

I am working on magento custom module, in module have `Setup\InstallSchema.php` file which is installed before. i have added some more database fields in `InstallSchema.php` so i want to update table structure but table have not applied any changes.

How i can apply schema changes to database table?

I have process cli commands to update schema but not success.

```
php bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade
```

and

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: You can uninstall with "php bin/magento module:uninstall"  and install your extension again. Another point to check it's UpgradeSchema.php like https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/9f0c1d61a1255259428361c53527a8d70efd2741#diff-16 Seems like at this moment here is no clean explanation how to upgrade the data base, so i also looking forward to correct answer here

Comment: @FireBear appy below answer code ?

Comment: not try yet, but looks correct according to sample from Catalog core module https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9f0c1d61a1255259428361c53527a8d70efd2741/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php

Comment: Most of the time, the error comes from not having a defined namespace for the class. Check that you have defined a namespace for you class.

Comment: Pls provide the code you have tried...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you want to add more column into existing table of your module you could do following.

**Step 1:** Create UpgradeSchema.php under Setup folder. Get Idea from following code.

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
class UpgradeSchema implements  UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
                            ModuleContextInterface $context){
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {

            // Get module table
            $tableName = $setup->getTable('table_name');

            // Check if the table already exists
            if ($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) == true) {
                // Declare data
                $columns = [
                    'imagename' => [
                        'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'comment' => 'image name',
                    ],
                ];

                $connection = $setup->getConnection();
                foreach ($columns as $name => $definition) {
                    $connection->addColumn($tableName, $name, $definition);
                }

            }
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** Change the `setup_version` value in `module.xml`

**Step 3:** Run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command from CLI

Comment: can you exmplain how i can add primary key using upgrade script ? in my table have 'customer_id' but it is not primary key now i want to add it as primary key.

Comment: Yes, you can change it using modifyColumnByDdl() function. Following is the schema.
` public function modifyColumn($tableName, $columnName, $definition, $flushData = false, $schemaName = null);`

Comment: How i can apply 'custome_id' field as primary key ? explain code exanple.

Comment: Can you please Add  "How we can modified type of existing column ?" in your question?

Comment: How to apply multiple upgradeschema ? Like in magento1 we have mysql4-upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1 ? @PrafulRajput

Comment: @Keyur Shah, you do not need to create a new file M2. 
You have to put following code into UpgradeSchema.php and update setup_version into module.xml as well.

if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0) { // you code }

if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) { // your code}

Comment: @PrafulRajput, My version is "1.0.0", so if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0', '<')) {} now it will work or not?

Answer (score 2):

To upgrade Installer Schema you have to write 'UpgradeSchema.php',

example of UpgradeSchema.php:

```
namespace <namespace>\<modulename>\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;

/**
* @codeCoverageIgnore
*/
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;

    $installer->startSetup();

    /*your code here*/

    $installer->endSetup();
}
}
```

Step 2: In your module you will find module.xml inside etc folder 
 in that file change setup_version value(ex: 1.0.1 to 1.0.2) version value should be higher then current version value.

Step 3: Run php bin/magento setup:upgrade command from CLI