# Magento 2 - How to add Attribute for cms_page?

Tags: magento2, attributes, cms

I knew how to add attributes for product entity:

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'period_date_start',/* Custom Attribute Code */
                [
                        'group' => 'Period Date',/* Group name in which you want to display your custom attribute */
                        'type' => 'datetime',/* Data type in which formate your value save in database*/
                        'frontend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\Datetime',
                        'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Datetime',
                        'label' => 'Start Date', /* lablel of your attribute*/
                        'input' => 'date',
                        'class' => '',
                        'source' => '', /* Source of your select type custom attribute options*/
                        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, /*Scope of your attribute */
                        'visible' => true,
                        'required' => false,
                        'user_defined' => true,
                        'default' => '',
                        'searchable' => false,
                        'filterable' => false,
                        'comparable' => false,
                        'visible_on_front' => false,
                        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                        'unique' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 1
                ]
        );
```

But how to add Attribute for cms_page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution below, it can solve my problem

> If you want to add more column into existing table of your module you
>   could do following.
>
> **Step 1:** Create UpgradeSchema.php under Setup folder. Get Idea from following code.
>
> ```
> namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup;
>
> use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
> use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
> use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
> class UpgradeSchema implements  UpgradeSchemaInterface
> {
>     public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
>                             ModuleContextInterface $context){
>         $setup->startSetup();
>         if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
>
>             // Get module table
>             $tableName = $setup->getTable('table_name');
>
>             // Check if the table already exists
>             if ($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) == true) {
>                 // Declare data
>                 $columns = [
>                     'imagename' => [
>                         'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
>                         'nullable' => false,
>                         'comment' => 'image name',
>                     ],
>                 ];
>
>                 $connection = $setup->getConnection();
>                 foreach ($columns as $name => $definition) {
>                     $connection->addColumn($tableName, $name, $definition);
>                 }
>
>             }
>         }
>
>         $setup->endSetup();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> **Step 2:** Change the `setup_version` value in `module.xml`
>
> **Step 3:** Run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command from CLI

link: [Magento2 : How to database schema upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86085/magento2-how-to-database-schema-upgrade)

Comment: Can you please explain this more clear. Because I have created the  UpgradeSchema.php in my module under setup folder and I executed the command wahat you have mentioned above. But No custom attributes reflected in CMS page. Kindly help me.

Comment: The install scripts that I have seen have a command like $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table) after all of the definitions.

Perhaps your data is correct but it isn't fully processing or attempting a save? I'm not sure if that createTable or a similar updateTable is necessary.

Comment: To be honest, this isn't the correct answer as the solution is impossible as worded in the question - I had the same problem as you.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the source for the CMS module, and the way they're adding the attributes is good enough for me. I would prefer a setup object like category or product, but I see nothing wrong with this.

```
     /**
     * Create table 'cms_page'
     */
    $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
        $installer->getTable('cms_page')
    )->addColumn(
        'page_id',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        null,
        ['identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
        'Page ID'
    );

    $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
```

Reference:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/Setup/InstallSchema.php

Comment: It is impossible to add EAV attributes to Cms/Page model - this is currently the only option (2.1.4)