# Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'adminhtml_customer-147' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: magento2, forms, customer-attribute

I have question about add new customer fields. Trying to add two fields like this:

MyModules\CustomerMarketingFields\Setup\InstallData.php

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $customerSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "regulation",  array(
            "type"     => "int",
            "backend"  => "",
            "label"    => "Regulamin",
            "input"    => "boolean",
            "source"   => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            "visible"  => true,
            "required" => true,
            "default" => "",
            "frontend" => "",
            "unique"     => false,
            "note"       => ""

        ));

        $regulation   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "regulation");

        $regulation = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'regulation');
        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
        $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $regulation->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", 100);
        $regulation->save();


        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "process_personal_data",  array(
            "type"     => "int",
            "backend"  => "",
            "label"    => "Personal data",
            "input"    => "boolean",
            "source"   => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            "visible"  => true,
            "required" => true,
            "default" => "",
            "frontend" => "",
            "unique"     => false,
            "note"       => ""

        ));
        $personalData   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "process_personal_data");

        $personalData = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'process_personal_data');
        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
        $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $personalData->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", 100);
        $personalData->save();

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
```

After run setup:upgrade command i get error like this:

```
 [Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]                                                
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'adminhtml_customer-147' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `customer_form_attribute` (`form_code`,`attribute_id`) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?) 

  [PDOException]                                                               
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'admi  
  nhtml_customer-147' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

When I add only one field everything is ok.
What is wrong with this config?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting twice `$used_in_forms`.
So in `$personalData->setData()` you pass:

```
$used_in_forms = [
   ...
   "adminhtml_customer"
   "adminhtml_customer"
   ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your install class name should be InstallSchema (setup/InstallSchema.php).

& many other changes needed Hope this link will help you.

[Magento 2 Database upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86085/magento2-how-to-database-schema-upgrade)

Comment: File is properly run and  when I add only one field everything is ok, so I think that the problem is somewhere else. 
Schema is changed when I want for example add column to existing database I think.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same code and same error showing on my screen.
Than I have checked the "`customer_form_attribute`" table into database and found that it has to columns `"form_code" and "attribute_id"`, both are setup as a primary keys.
I have just remove the primary key from the `"form_code"` column and run the script again by deleting the our module entry from `"setup_module"` table.

And now all working for me and created two customer attribute "Regulamin" and "Personal data" into admin customer add/edit section.

I have changed into table structure manually.I don't know its best practice or not but its working now.::)