# Magento 2 - InstallData.php does not run again after first time

Tags: magento2, install-script, setup-upgrade, data-install

I have created my custom module to add more attributes for customers.

The `InstallData.php` worked perfectly for the first time and added all the attributes I wanted.

However, I need to add more attributes. I updated my `InstallData.php` and run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, but the new attributes are not added.

What did I miss in this problem?

Comment: I think I found out why,  I must delete my modules from setup_module and then run setup:upgrade? I thought by giving a higher module version in module.xml is enough.

Comment: check my answer, it will help you more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete your module from `setup_module` table and run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: so I i just give a higher version in module.xml, this won't help? must record from setup_module be deleted everytime I want to run setup:upgrade?

Comment: If you want to to use versioning, you need to create new file [UpgradeSchema.php], and add your code here, please follow this it has more information . https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/86089/31830

Answer (score 1):

Delete your module from `setup_module` table in a database and also require to delete your database table which is useful in `InstallData.php`.

If you don't want to delete your database table then you can also use `UpgradeSchema.php` file to add more attributes in the database.

Create `Vendor/Module/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();
        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('table_name'),
            'table_field_name',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'length' => '2M',
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => null,
                'comment' => 'Custom Attribute',
            ]
        );
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The right way of doing it is using UpgradeData. This way you don't touch on the already existing data installed by InstallData.  Only thing to note is change the `setup_version` in module.xml.

There is an answer for this question already [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/254790/upgradedata-to-add-a-custom-customer-attribute-is-not-working-in-magento2)