# `upgradeData` to add a custom customer attribute is not working in `Magento2`

Tags: magento2.2, customer, customer-attribute

I've created few `customer` attribute using `upgradeData.php`. The content of the `upgradeData.php` is as below,

```
<?php


namespace Ucs\CustomerAttribute\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "1.0.0", "<")) {

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'country_code', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Country Code',
                'input' => 'text',
                'source' => '',
                'required' => true,
                'visible' => true,
                'position' => 333,
                'system' => false,
                'backend' => ''
            ]);

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'country_code')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                    'adminhtml_customer',
                    'adminhtml_checkout',
                    'customer_account_create',
                    'customer_account_edit'
                ]
            ]);
            $attribute->save();
        }

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "1.0.0", "<")) {

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Mobile',
                'input' => 'text',
                'source' => '',
                'required' => true,
                'visible' => true,
                'position' => 333,
                'system' => false,
                'backend' => ''
            ]);

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'mobile')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                    'adminhtml_customer',
                    'adminhtml_checkout',
                    'customer_account_create',
                    'customer_account_edit'
                ]
            ]);
            $attribute->save();
        }

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2', '<')) {

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'is_mobile_verified', [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                'label' => 'Is Mobile Verified?',
                'input' => 'checkbox',
                'source' => '',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'position' => 333,
                'system' => false,
                'backend' => ''
            ]);

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'is_mobile_verified')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                    'adminhtml_customer'
                ]
            ]);
            $attribute->save();
       }
    }
}
```

And `module.xml` as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Ucs_CustomerAttribute" setup_version="1.0.2">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

However, the attribute has not been created but `setup_module` table has got updated  as `data_version` with version number 1.0.2.

Anyway, to make sure that `upgrade()` method is executed I removed the condition `if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2', '<')) { }`   so that the script to add `is_mobile_verified` will be executed. Still I don't see the field gets added into the table.

I checked `debug.log` and `system.log` but no log is captured related to this.

Comment: please check my answer.

Comment: @RohanHapani thanks for your reply. Let me try.

Comment: Make sure your module version in setup_module table and don't forgot to upgrade setup and flush cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set schema_version also in xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Ucs_CustomerAttribute" setup_version="1.0.2" schema_version="1.0.2">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

And use this below code in your **upgradeData** file :

```
<?php


namespace Ucs\CustomerAttribute\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

         if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0) {

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'country_code', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Country Code',
                'input' => 'text',
                'source' => '',
                'required' => true,
                'visible' => true,
                'position' => 333,
                'system' => false,
                'backend' => ''
            ]);

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'country_code')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                    'adminhtml_customer',
                    'adminhtml_checkout',
                    'customer_account_create',
                    'customer_account_edit'
                ]
            ]);
            $attribute->save();
        }

         if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0) {

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Mobile',
                'input' => 'text',
                'source' => '',
                'required' => true,
                'visible' => true,
                'position' => 333,
                'system' => false,
                'backend' => ''
            ]);

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'mobile')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                    'adminhtml_customer',
                    'adminhtml_checkout',
                    'customer_account_create',
                    'customer_account_edit'
                ]
            ]);
            $attribute->save();
        }

         if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2') < 0) {

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'is_mobile_verified', [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                'label' => 'Is Mobile Verified?',
                'input' => 'checkbox',
                'source' => '',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'position' => 333,
                'system' => false,
                'backend' => ''
            ]);

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'is_mobile_verified')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                    'adminhtml_customer'
                ]
            ]);
            $attribute->save();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry, I made other mistake, Now it seems the upgradedata is executing, however I am getting other error as `\Setup\Table`

Comment: which error ..?

Comment: `'type' => Table::TYPE_BIGINT` caused this issue. and as per dev docs I updated as `'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_BIGINT` it works fine.

Comment: Could you please clarify one thing? What is the use of `setup_version` and `schema_version` in module.xml ?

Comment: setup version is for identify your module version & schema version is used for identify schema version. Means when you upgrade your module at that time if schema and setup version match then approriate your condition code will be execute from file.

Comment: so it is not necessary to change the `setup_version` if I want to add only few more fields? In that case only updating `schema_version` is enough?

Comment: No. When you upgrade module at that time, setup_version and schema_version must need to change. If setup_version will not change that magento will consider as like no need to change into table because, your module's version was not upgrade into setup_module table.

Comment: @RohanHapani, How to add multiple attributes at a time?

Comment: You can ask separate question :) It's helpful in future for other developers. It's little bit different so.